# Multiple Transport Support in Single web service

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, cxf, jax-ws

I am using cxf with spring. I have requirement to expose same service to support multiple transport. Technically a a single Web Service will have multiple port and each port can handle individual transport like

````
```    <service>
```    <port name="soap1.1.">-----</port>
```    <port name="soap1.2">----</port>
```    <port name="httpget">----</port>
```    <port name="httppost">----</port>
```    </service>
````

I am able to expose service with single port for different transport i need to create different endpoint. Any help here?

Comment: Hi Omkar,  I'm a little bit confused by how you use the word "transport".  I think transport is things like HTTP or RMI or MQTT.  In your question, I think all of them use the same transport: HTTP.  To expose the same remote service through REST (HTTP Get & Put etc) and SOAP, I would suggest different URLs.  Such as:
http://host/soap/myservice and http://host/rest/myservice.  If you still want to use different ports, that configuration probably is part of the app server you run CXF on.  SpringBoot, usually runs on Tomcat and Jetty.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks dev, I want to invoke service with browser url something like http:<host>:<port>/service/methodname?param=value. I can get my service response using soap request but idea to get response in browser.